# Is the Energy of the fast move more important than DPS due to how fast it can make a charge move possible?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is the fast move's Energy actually more important than DPS?  For example, one fast move may have a DPS 12.9, and the other one has a DPS of 10.2, so we may tend to prefer the one with DPS 12.9.

But what if the DPS 10.2 move can charge up a Hydro Pump or Blizzard faster than the other fast move, and therefore this fast move can do more DPS because the charge move can be used faster? (and more frequently)

PS: I do not know of a good example yet, but if we look at [Exeggutor](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/exeggutor.html) first, its Confusion has DPS of 12.4 and Zen Headbutt has DPS of 14.3 (both have STAB). Therefore, maybe the Zen Headbutt is a better move.  But Confusion can charge up a Solar Beam at the rate of 7 Energy, while Zen Headbutt can charge the Solar Beam up at the rate of 4 Energy. So wouldn't that actually make Confusion a better move?

Another example is [Snorlax](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/snorlax.html), when Zen Headbutt has 10% more DPS than Lick, but Lick can charge up the Energy by 7, while Zen Headbutt is only 4, so Lick has 75% higher speed for charging up the energy for a Body Slam, Hyper Beam, or Earthquake.

Comment: Did you really mean to ask “is this often overlooked”? That's not a question for Arqade, because it is about *the players*, not *the game*. I suggest you edit that out and just focus on asking if the charge energy matters.

Comment: So the question actually could just mean "does the Energy of fast move affect how fast a fast move is charged up and therefore is more important than DPS?" *[pruned several remarks and comments about communication]*

Comment: This is a reference site, and your question and its answers are expected to serve as a resource to future users who find it during their own research. Please be clear and concise.

Comment: When I say how fast a move charge up energy, is it often overlooked. That means isn't that important and why does the usual strategy not consider that. That is all clear. If you have to go into "the forum is about the game. It is not about the players," then you might be going into the little things and forget about the main thing.

Comment: Therein lies your problem: You say "the usual strategy," but we cannot determine whose strategy it is that you consider "usual." In communities like this one or The Silph Road, where people are very rigorous about the game, "the usual strategy" is based on using spreadsheets to calculate the energy-respective DPS of a whole moveset. This, to me, is "the usual strategy" and it does not overlook energy too much at all. On a site like the one you linked to (pokemongodb), however, the data is outdated and has been subjected to much less analysis. On there, yes, EPS *is* overlooked.

Comment: Regardless of our little slap-fight here, however, your subsequent revisions to this question have made it better, and made your real inquiry easier to answer. I was not one of the people to downvote it, before, but I *am* upvoting it, now.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is known as an opportunity cost, and yes, many people who play games (or who indulge in any sort of economizing) are bad at taking it into full consideration.

**There are certainly circumstances in which a greater rate of Energy Per Second is more important than raw DPS**; your given example of a Snorlax who can select either Zen Headbutt (emphasizing DPS) or Lick (emphasizing EPS) is one such example. With Hyperbeam as its charge move, a Snorlax on assault can expect an overall rate of 17.4 damage per second if it has Lick, but only 16.7 if it is using Zen Headbutt.

**However, in circumstances where the gain in EPS is too small compared to the loss of DPS, a basic move with greater DPS *is* the better choice.** The Exeggutor to which you refered is an example of this, actually: Yes, Confusion will generate slightly more energy per second than Zen Headbutt, but the loss of damage per second is too great to be made up for by using charge attacks with the slight extra frequency that this extra energy permits.

There are also circumstances where the difference in quality of charge attacks may make EPS more or less desirable. For example, a Beedrill with Sludge Bomb or X-Scissor as its charge move would be better off with the superior EPS of Bug Buzz as its basic move. On the other hand, a Beedrill can come with the charge move Aerial Ace, which is *so* bad that it is preferable to completely ignore it and just always use basic moves. In this case, it would be better off with Poison Jab, which emphasizes DPS.

This math changes if the Pokémon under consideration is destined to defend a gym instead of attack them; There is an average delay of 2 seconds between every attack that such a defender undertakes, and to make up for this, they get twice the HP reserve. A Pokémon gains 1 energy for every 2 damage sustained, so this means a defending Pokemon enjoys preportionally more energy per attack than one on offense. On the other hand, a defending Pokémon with the opportunity to unleash a charge move will only choose to do so half the time. These factors make highly-damaging basic moves far more important.